# ListView: setting up OnItemClick

Tags: android, arrays, listview, onitemclick, android-toast

Sorry for my language. How to show a particular image(covering the whole screen) for each list item, i mean that after clicking on item 1 an image 1 should appear, after clicking on item 2 an image 2 should appear, etc. I used Toast, but could not manage to show different pics for different items. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is...
On click of an list item invoke a new Activity with your image in full screen (in the view).

Edited:
Assuming listView is your listView item

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
    //Invoke new activity with image id/name.
    //In new activity depending upon image id/name show the image.
  }

});
```

Comment: Yes, but, as I mentioned in my question, how do I invoke different Activities for different list items, that is the problem. Thank you

Comment: @user3158610 check the edited part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Activity that only shows the image, covering the whole screen as you want.

A Dialog is another alternative for this case, you can set its layout and pop it up, covering the current activity as well.

Comment: Yes, but, as I mentioned in my question, how do I invoke different Activities or Dialogs for different list items, that is the problem. Thank you

Comment: The Activity will be "generic" so every item in the list will be passed via extras for the new Activity. In this new activity you can handle every extra you receive.
If you want to show an image, you can pass the image path, URI or resource ID, then, in your new activity, you show it.